# Отрисовка графиков посредством Matplotlib в окне Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, matplotlib

Доброго времени суток!

Реализую визуализацию данных с датчиков. Разобрался как с помощью модуля `matplotlib` строить графики.

Так же разобрался с графическим интерфейсом, реализация с помощью `tkinter`.

По отдельности ничего сложного. Однако у меня стоит задача - выводить графики непосредственно в окне приложения.

И тут я вообще не понимаю в какую сторону смотреть что бы разобраться.

И так, каким образом в реальном времени возможно вставить построенный посредством `matplotlib` график в окно создание посредством `tkinter`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот [туториал](https://pythonprogramming.net/how-to-embed-matplotlib-graph-tkinter-gui/)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)


class SeaofBTCapp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self, default="clienticon.ico")
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Sea of BTC client")


        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo, PageThree):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Start Page", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button = ttk.Button(self, text="Visit Page 1",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button.pack()

        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Visit Page 2",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button2.pack()

        button3 = ttk.Button(self, text="Graph Page",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageThree))
        button3.pack()


class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Page One!!!", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Page Two",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button2.pack()


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Page Two!!!", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Page One",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button2.pack()


class PageThree(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Graph Page!", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

        f = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)
        a = f.add_subplot(111)
        a.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[5,6,1,3,8,9,3,5])



        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
        canvas.show()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, self)
        toolbar.update()
        canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)



app = SeaofBTCapp()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: чтобы избежать [TclError](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20860325/4279), пришлось `tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self, default="clienticon.ico")` заменить на         `self.iconbitmap('@python.xbm')` на Ubuntu. Для рисунка здесь только импорты и `PageThree` полезны.